# Is moved variable valid to use after std::move?

Tags: c++, move

I'm having hard time to understand if I `std::move` POD from one variable to another, is the source variable still valid to use or does it act something like dangling pointer? does it still point to stack memory?

for example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = std::move(a) // b owns a resources now

a = 10 // is this valid? does it have memory address?
std::cout << a; // prints 10 obviously valid?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` does nothing to a POD.

```
int a = 5;
int b = std::move(a);
```

`a` is still good after that.

For non-POD types, the moved object maybe valid for some operations and invalid for other operations -- it all depends on what the move constructor or move assignment operator does.

Comment: Maybe you should extend the answer to include the behavior for non-POD types.

Comment: @CinCout, the behavior for non-POD types depends so much on the move constructor, it's hard to say anything useful about them.

Comment: so is the only purpose of std::move for invoking move asignment and move consturctos? any other case beside these 2 concepts?

Comment: @zebanovich Move semantic is not restricted in any way. Any function can more from any argument.

Comment: @zebanovich, that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `std::move` does not move its argument, it just casts it to an rvalue reference. What actually moves an object is a constructor or an assignment operator that accept rvalue reference.

But `int` is a built-in type and does not have such a constructor or `operator=`, so applying `std::move` to `int` will not cause it to get moved.

Putting built-in types aside, the C++ Standard says that a moved-from object should be in a valid but unspecified state. Usually, it means that we cannot use its value, but can re-assign it.

Comment: That last bit is also a requirement for std types: you can call functions without preconditions without a problem (although calling size on a moved from vector will still be unspecified, even though it won't cause undefined behaviour). Moved from std smart pointers are also set to nullptr, which is another additional feature defined in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `std::move` on a `POD` type, nothing special happens it just makes a plain *copy* and both the *source* and *destination* are still usable.